# How can I sync two forks of a github repo?

Tags: git, github

I am a contributor to several forks of an open source project. The main repo of the project is City72 (https://github.com/city72/city-72/network)

I have one fork, Community72 where I have abstracted all of the strings from the views so that the site can be ready for translation. However, it is so significantly different from City72 that I can't just make a pull request back to City72.

Meanwhile, I'm working on a different, older, fork: Oak72. I'd like to sync Oak72 with Community72. I know it's possible, but I don't know how to send the pull request from Community72 to Oak72.

How can I pull from one fork to the other via GitHub?

Comment: Do you need to do this via the GitHub web interface? GitHub tracks merges across repositories just fine, even if they were not made via the web interface.

Comment: I got help from a friend on this... the answer is git rebase... I'll try to explain it clearly, but in a nutshell. I set the remote to the other fork and then did git rebase.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to (good) questions.

Comment: @ChristophSommer I should! I'm not 100% sure I can articulate the steps, but I will try.

Answer (score 0):

First, from the fork that you want to receive the new code set it's remote to be the other fork. (in my case I set Oak72 to look at Community72 as it's remote)

Second, from the fork that you want to receive the new code updates run 'git rebase'

Resolve any conflicts (I used Source Tree to do it ..but it can be done in terminal as well)

Then, continue the rebase.

Then, finally, your fork should match the other fork.